# EditText focus is not working in android studio, i want to hide a textview when focus change in edittext, how to do this?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext, onfocuschangelistener

**EditText as ChangeContact**

**EditText focus is not working in android studio, i want to hide a textview when focus change in edittext, how to do this?**

```
       ChangeContact.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (!hasFocus) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "focus loosed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "focused", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        bookLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

My edit text in XMl file

```
  <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etChangeAddress"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_transparent"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Address"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etChangeNumber"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

**But i cant see the Toast**

Please help ....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this for ChangeContact?

```
 android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

also
ChangeContact.requestFocus() ?

Comment: Yes I changed in xml file too but it doesn't works, I dont know why ...

Comment: <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etChangeAddress"
                   
                 
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                  
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
               
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

Comment: how to set this requestFocus ? in class i cleared focus when onCreate

Comment: i called this ChangeContact.requestFocus(); but not works

Comment: I hope you initialize listner before you did on focus operation

Comment: @ShaikAbdullah mark success if helped you

Answer (score 0):

In my case I can't get on focus change event because I forgot to delete `setContentView()` function and used it with binding initialization like this:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
 binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, null, false)
```

also eventually I understood that binding initialization also was incorrect